# Set and Display current Data on ng-click?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, yeoman, angularjs-ng-click

I'm using Yeoman - angular generator.
JSBin: [JSBin Link](http://jsbin.com/OGipAVUF/3/)

I have a simple list of airports being set from a factory `angApp.factory("Airports", function() {});` and displayed from ng-repeat `<ul ng-repeat="airport in airports.detail">`.

[image]

I would like to have an interaction that when each link is clicked it will match the airport code and display it in a new paragraph tag `<p class="current">Current: {{currentAirport.name}}</p>`.

Why wont the `setAirport(airport.code)` function set  the `currentAirport.name`(or display?) when airport link is clicked in html?

**Controller**

```
angular.module("ang6App")
  .controller("AirportsCtrl", function ($scope, Airports) {
    $scope.formURL = "views/_form.html";
    $scope.currentAirport = null;
    $scope.airports = Airports;
    $scope.setAirport = function(code) {
      $scope.currentAirport = $scope.airports[code];
    };

  });
```

**Factory Service in the same module**

```
angApp.factory("Airports", function() {
    var Airports = {};
    Airports.detail = {
        "PDX": {
          "code": "PDX",
          "name": "Portland International Airport",
          "city": "Portland",
          "destinations": [
            "LAX",
            "SFO"
          ]
        },
        "STL": {
          "code": "STL",
          "name": "Lambert-St. Louis International Airport",
          "city": "St. Louis",
          "destinations": [
            "LAX",
            "MKE"
          ]
        },
        "MCI": {
          "code": "MCI",
          "name": "Kansas City International Airport",
          "city": "Kansas City",
          "destinations": [
            "LAX",
            "DFW"
          ]
        }
      };
    return Airports;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="AirportsCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="airport in airports.detail">
    <li><a href="" ng-click="setAirport(airport.code)">{{airport.code}}</a> -- {{airport.city}} </li>
  </ul>
  <p class="current"> current: {{currentAirport.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you setup a fiddle that shows this [not] working?

Comment: Yes I will try.  I'm pretty bad at scaffolding angular applications (kind of cheatting using yeoman to get my barrings)

Comment: When ever you can post the answer I'm actively waiting to mark it correct.  Or if you have any more questions I awaiting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `setAirport` function should be written as:

```
$scope.setAirport = function (code) {
  $scope.currentAirport = $scope.airports.detail[code];
};
```

But then, this could be simplified by passing the actual `airport` object directly:

```
<a href ng-click="setAirport(airport)">{{airport.code}}</a>

$scope.setAirport = function (airport) {
  $scope.currentAirport = airport;
};
```

Comment: Which is the preferred method? I feel the simplified answer is easier to retain.  However, is there any time that it wouldn't be appropriate?

Comment: Each method provides you with the exact same `airport` object so simplicity wins. The only time where this might not work is when you're, for example, removing an entry from the array, in which case you want to pass in the index value (for splice), instead of the actual object.